# Deciding function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a beginner in sql.

I need confirmation on whether i am choosing the right function.

I am writing a query where i want to list the purchaser id's of the purchasers that have the most number of ticket purchases.
Would this be done through COUNT(*) and MAX ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would do this by `GROUP BY` the purchaser's id and then `ORDER BY` the `COUNT(*)` of the rows in `DESC`ending order and then, from Oracle 12c, can use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` to get those with the greatest number of purchases.

You do not need to use `MAX` (although I'm sure there are variants of the query where you could use it).

Since this appears to be a homework question, I'll leave creating the entire query to you.